# I want to break at Meltdown

Tags: javascript, r-markdown

Even if I break in the middle of a line in [Meltdown](http://iphands.github.io/Meltdown/), in the preview column it will not break in the middle of the line.

How can I fix it in order to break a line in the middle?

---

**default**

> A JQuery plugin that adds Markdown Extra live previews, and a toolbar
>   for common markdown actions.

---

**I want to change like below.**

> A JQuery plugin that adds Markdown Extra live previews,
>   and a toolbar for common markdown actions.

Comment: I think this stems from a misunderstanding of Markdown rather than a bug; you need to add two spaces to the end of the line, then a line break, to give a line break in Markdown. A single linebreak without a space **does nothing**. See the [Markdown reference](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) for a good explanation of this.

Comment: I noticed that I misunderstood. Thank you